# UsingClickOnce in order to update my tool and game

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have a C# software and with software we can log in in a game. This software also performs the automatic update of the game files.

I have 3 problems:
- Requires the 4.0 framework minimum (I limited myself to 4.0 because of Windows XP) and some people do not have it, and it's not easy for everyone to know what to do, where to download, etc etc .
- The software used to update the game can not update itself, which makes sense
- The game works from an .exe file and if I update it via my application, most antivirus programs block it

I want that ClickOnce show if there is an available update of my application before I start it.

I want to know if it's possible that ClickOnce update the game files (3500 files in total). If I do an update, there are less than 20 updated/modified files.

I want that ClickOnce shows if the framework 4.0 or 4.5 is installed.

```
[https://image.prntscr.com/image/vL9qZWdaQ0aVxMJIoy---Q.png][1]
[https://image.prntscr.com/image/KWDxtMQtQGan9ml2iA17-A.png][2]
[https://image.prntscr.com/image/yRclvHNgQC22WILpY8ehmw.png][3]
```

But ClickOnce never says that there is an available update ...

And we need to use the setup.exe ? It is not possible to download my game, and that ClickOnce is automatically used before that application is started ?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Your ClickOnce application should have .NET as prerequsite and prior to installing app, you can install .NET.

[How to: Install Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[How to: Specify a Support URL for Individual Prerequisites in a ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404264%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You can Add update options. Go through below link
[Manage Updates for a ClickOnce Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zyc39fb.aspx)

Comment: Hi,

It works, I have checked the box in order to have a desktop icone after the installation. 

But I see that we can't choose the installation folder ...

The problem is that I want to use clickonce in order to update the connexion software of my game server, and in order to download all 3500 files of the game, and update them each time that update are available.

This is not possible ?